# How to follow a question on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, follow-post

Is there a way to follow a question on Stack Overflow? I would like to mark a question and be notified when there's been some progress (e.g., a comment or an answer). Is this possible?

Answer (score 24):

Mark it as favorite.
See star icon downward vote buttons.
And you can always access it in your Profile page in **favorites** tab.

Comment: Thanks. Should've paid closer attention.

Comment: Bit of a confusing mental model. Favorites and Following are two different patterns IMHO.

Comment: IOW I may not like a question, and hence I feel dissonance click "Favorite" because it's not my favorite. Hence the interface is forcing me to think like it.

I may just want to follow something.

Comment: Thanks for the info...I was looking for it for long time..

Comment: Honestly, I don't want to pollute my Favorites list with many questions for which I am only interested in the answer... The site should definitely have a "follow this question" functionality besides the Favorites.

Comment: I agree and am looking for the same functionality. One suggestion is that in the bottom right of every question page there is actually a "Question feed" which I will use for now to get updated (RSS). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the infos, isn't obvious nor intuitive.

Comment: I agree, it would be nice to really FOLLOW the question, meaning you will get a notification in the top left notification menu when something happens in the followed question

Comment: That wasn't obvious. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm in agreement on the Follow.. and get notifications in a way similar to Quora

Comment: Has that been done?

Comment: If you would like to follow an entire category of questions (by "tag"), hover over the tag and click "Subscribe"

Comment: I request email notification for my favorite.

Comment: @killer how do you do that?

Comment: Just a comment to follow.

Comment: And now it's called "Bookmark this question", which makes it three different terms for same action =-D

Comment: And now: *[Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves)*